# Strange output of a very simple code?

Tags: function, math, sage

I'm very new to python, but I found this strange:
 Code: I was typing in Sagemathcloud's sageworksheet file:

```
x=y+1
def f(x):
    return y
x=-1
print(x)
print(f(x))
```

As an output, I kept getting 7 or sometimes 49, something quite randomnumbers no matter what value of x I input. Any insights please?

P.S. I'm trying to make it look like a code, but I'm, not sure how to do that, for example, def was in the next lmine after I typed: x=y+1.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the only code you have, then `y` isn't defined before it is used. `y` will take the value of what was previously in the memory space it's using - and that may not even be an int which causes the randomness of the numbers you're experiencing.

Comment: Then why is the following not a problem? x and y are not defined apriori?

`{z=[x,y]
def f(z):
    return x+y
x=2
y=6
print(f(z))
x=2
y=6}`

Comment: Seems some kind of crazy error from the sagemathcloud itself, because I just did and got it alright:

`y=x-1
def f(x):
     return y
x=8
print(f(x))`

Comment: I'm not sure, but this code is python, and `x = y + 1` will throw a runtime error, so the SageMathCloud is doing something to correct that, and that something is unpredictable.

Comment: It's interesting that Sage is correcting only for the case z=[x,y], where x and y are not defined, but it's not doing any such correction when I type the program with y=x-1.

Comment: Also, the following is giving me an error: 

 ` 
 z=[x,y]
w=[a,b]
def f(z,w):
    return x+b
x=3
y=7
a=5
b=6
print(f(z,w)) 

`